# Is it possible to send request to external service when AWS IoT Core got mqtt message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices, iot, aws-iot

I have to use AWS IoT Core as my MQTT broker and send MQTT msg from my devices. I want to store the msg in an external service like a database when the IoT core received the MQTT data. I know AWS IoT Core can use a rule to route data to lambda but I see the policy template is available with other AWS services only. I'm curious if there is a way to send it to non-AWS services. The service has its REST interface to ingest data. I'm fine to host the service on AWS EC2 if need.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my abecedarian question. Lambda function of cause can access external services. Just need to make the program with a workable running environment layer.